# Increased processing Capability of Computer in handing large graphs

Tags: c++, stl, graph-algorithm, heap-memory, netbeans-8

I was running a modified version of Dijkstra's(implemented in C++ using STL)+DFS on my PC(using NetBeans IDE) and feeding it with large size random graphs. I noticed that when the number of vertices was increased to around 50000V and the number of edges to around 500000E, NetBeans showed me a heap overflow error. Is there any way, I can increase this processing power capability of my computer or Are there any options available for processing such large graphs for free on Internet.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code probably has a bug, but there's no way we can help you fix it since we can't see your code. Dijkstra's should easily handle graphs of that size.

Comment: *Are there any options available for processing such large graphs for free on Internet.* -- [Boost Graph Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html)

Comment: Could you tell until what size of graph is your PC able to handle? Like approximately how much time is it taking to process it? I think it also has something to do with 64bit vs 32 bit. I am using a 64-bit version of Windows with Netbeans IDE.